# Move partition from ssd disk to pendrive

Tags: disk, mbr, dd

I have a 128 GB SSD. There is one partition: `sda1` - 12 GB. I tried to move this partition to a USB pendrive.

The pendrive is 16 GB in size.

I booted from a live medium and ran:

```
dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/sdc1
```

then I copied the MBR from `sda`:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=mbrbackup bs=512 count=1
```

and restored it on `sdc`:

```
dd if=mbrbackup of=/dev/sdc bs=446 count=1
```

Unfortunately the OS did not boot from the USB. What did I miss ?

Comment: I don't think you can move a partition. But you can get around this: Copy and paste the partition to the USB and then delete the partition on the SSD, or clone it yourself (filesystem, and files and etc.)

Comment: Why not just a new install. You cannot have duplicate UUIDs and you did not copy grub2's core.img which is just after the MBR. If not new install then kyodake suggestion to create partitions, so you do not have duplicate UUIDs, copy with rsync & reinstall grub is best solution. But you may still have some other internal setting configured for old drive that should be cleaned up, depending on what is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Create a new partition table and ext4 partition on the USB drive (/dev/sdc1)

Open a terminal and clone /dev/sda1 through rsync:

```
sudo -i
rsync -aAXv --exclude={"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/media/*","/lost+found"} /* /dev/sdc1
```

Using the -aAX set of options, the files are transferred in archive mode, ensuring that symbolic links, devices, permissions and ownerships, modification times, ACLs and extended attributes are preserved.

Update the /dev/sdc1/etc/fstab to reflect the UUID changes.

```
blkid
nano /dev/sdc1/etc/fstab
```

Update the bootloader and configuration files

```
umount /dev/sdc1
mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev 
mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
chroot /mnt
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sdc
grub-install --recheck /dev/sdc
umount /mnt
exit
```

Comment: Kyodake tnx for reply. It helped. There is only one thing. While creating partition on pendrive, first 1 MB should be free for MBR save. If not, then grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sdc will not work.

Comment: @tyo: The master boot record is created when a hard drive is partitioned, it is located on the first sector of a disk,  Cylinder: 0, Head: 0, Sector: 1.

Comment: I had below issue while installing grub on default created partition (on USB): 

Your embedding area is unusually small. core.img won't fit in it..

Embedding is not possible. GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists. However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..

error: will not proceed with blocklists


Manually create 1MB free space solved the problem